# Change file permission with PHP

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

i tried many ways but still can't figure it out,

```
function permission($proj,$mod){

 $dir = "../../../".$proj."/mod/".$mod."";


 var_dump($dir);

  echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($dir)), -4);

 $change = chmod($dir,0664);
 var_dump($change);

   echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($dir)), -4);


}
```

So $change returns boolean True which means everything was OK, but file at beginning have 0777 access and at the end it have still have 0777 permission... what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$dir = "../../../".$proj."/mod/".$mod."";`. Extra quote at the end. You can also use variables directly inside double quotes.

Comment: @Christian already tried, even with "/" but still same...

Comment: You may need to alter the umask of the files first.  So try wrapping the chmod line with `$oldmask = umask(0);` and then `umask($oldmask);`

Comment: @Andy i tried unmask it but still nothing, maybe i'm using unmask wrong? can you please show me example in this situation how i must unmask it?

Comment: @Dest Sorry, I added my comment without details - updated with the two lines you could try wrapping around your chmod line.

Comment: @Andy yeah that's how i did but it does not works... i did it again but same... any other ideas?

Comment: It may just be a caching thing.  The fileperms function uses stat() whose results are cached.  Before your second echo of fileperms try using `clearstatcache();` and see if that helps.  [clearstatcache manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)

Comment: @Andy nope still same. i used clearstatcache but nothing changed. anyway is there some other system based function which can change permission? i mean exec( chmod command here) or something like this? and if yes is it depending on OS? (i mean different command on different OS)

Comment: Something else to check; does the file you're trying to chmod belong to the same user that PHP is running under?  If not then PHP may not be able to change the permissions.

Comment: @Andy yes php copied that file from another directory and then i need change permission. when i`m checking manually file permission it really have all permissions for system user which are used by php